# Filtering a list in Google sheets by value of offset column

Tags: google-sheets

If I have a sheet laid out similar to the below:

```
      | T1 | T2 |   
one   | X  |    |
two   | X  |  X |
three |    |  X |
```

If there a way i can make a dynamically updated list of values from the first column where they have an X in the column offset by (say) one column from their own value ?

So in this case one list that'd be 'one and two' and one that'd include 'two and three'

Something like; `=FILTER(A2:A5, OFFSET("C[1]") == "X")`   ?

Up to now I've been using the funnel filter tool on the column built into the app, which works for smaller item numbers - but really i'd like to be able to have each filtered output on it's own worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) could be what you are looking for.

```
=QUERY(A2:C4,"select A where B='X' label A ''")
```

and

```
=QUERY(A2:C4,"select A where C='X' label A ''")
```